# how to position the table to cover full width of page

Tags: html, css

I have a below code to display the table. But i am not sure on how to place it to cover full width. Defined tbody as block for scrollable. i could get the expected result when remove those block line. but i would like to get scrollable as well as full width stretch. Please some one help me.

```css
/* table-itemtable styles */
.t1 table { border-collapse: collapse; }
.t1 th, td { text-align: center; padding: 8px;}
.t1 th {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;}
.t1 tr {border-bottom: 1px solid;}
.t1 tbody { display: block; }
.t1 tbody {
    height: 300px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" class="t1">
  <tr>
    <th> SLno</th>
    <th>Item name</th>
    <th>Item code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>icecream</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>biscuits</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>biscuits</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>biscuits</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>biscuits</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>biscuits</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>biscuits</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>biscuits</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.t1 tbody { display: block; }`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWOYNL

Comment: Thanks let me check

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

**HTML:**

In table u can add the `width`

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" class="t1" width="100%">
```

**CSS**

In CSS properties remove the `display`

```
.t1 tbody { display: block; }
```